# Android admin UploadinG Image To Server And The Client Can See It

Tags: android, android-studio, xampp, wamp

Basically 
My idea Is uploading image to server.

And At The Same Time Every Client THose Who Download App Should Recieve It. 
So What Should I Do So As To Implement This
Basic Requirements

All Should Be DOne in Android Studio

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)